# $_GET[] a value via jquery to php SQL statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is the jQuery to passing the `attr()` value to `$_GET[]`.  When I echo `$_GET[]` it displays the value. But not when I pass the `$_GET` into a `MySQL` statement.

```
$('.DetailsDisplay').click(function() {
          var ix = $(this).attr('id');
          $('#Details').load('details.php?regid='+ix);

       });
```

**details.php**

```
mysql_select_db($database_host, $host);
$query_list_class = "SELECT * FROM xfi where no='".stid."'";
$list_class = mysql_query($query_list_class, $sshost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_list_class = mysql_fetch_assoc($list_class);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you upload the code on details.php too?

Comment: post the code where you are passing to sql statement.

Comment: do not use `mysql_*` functions. It is deprecated. You should be using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Your code and the 2 examples are extremely prone to simple SQL injection, I'd recommend replacing this entire code... With something like PDO/Bind params at minimum.

Comment: did you try to print your sql code to ensure that it is not inserted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got no `$` sign in sql

```
$query_list_class = "SELECT * FROM xfi where no='".$stid."'";
```

PS: Also please parse `$stid` to `int`

```
$stid = (int) $_GET['regid'];
```

Comment: Thanks... too much coding had me overseeing things.

Comment: can you tell me whats reason to convert `$stid` to `int`

Comment: @krishna SQL injections? 
If column no of table xfi is INTEGER it's a great way of preventing SQL INJECTION

Comment: If you cast as int, do not do no='xx', you'd be treating it as a string and defeat the purpose. do no=x

Comment: @Mr.TK whats the reason to convert to int?

Comment: @X10nD The reason is to reduce SQL injections, if the user just enters the url `details.php?regid=33' or 1=1` it will return every single thing within xfi, where as (int) on regid will force it to 33. Its a bit hacky imo, you should not be using mysql_* and look into something like PDO with BindParams.

Comment: _“too much coding had me overseeing things”_ – no, too much !$%# had you not have proper error reporting enabled … so please do so immediately.

Answer (score 3):

**you forgot `$` sign**

also make sure to prevent [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
$stid = intval($_GET['regid']);

$query_list_class = "SELECT * FROM xfi where no='".$stid."'";
```

**note :** don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated, use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** instead

Comment: Thanks... too much coding had me overseeing things.